# Passing pipeline item to promise argument in `takeUntil`

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have code with a similar control flow to this example (obviously, the predicate below doesn't need to be `async`, but it's an example):

```
const items [1,2,3,4,5];
const predicate = async (i) => i < 3;
const pipeline = from(items).pipe(
  takeUntil(predicate),
);

pipeline.subscribe(console.log);
```

But this throws a `TypeError` with the message "You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable."

I've tried making `predicate` a promise (`new Promise(...)`, and using `takeWhile` in place of `takeUntil` but neither worked as expected (the promise always returned true - I am assuming it is coerced to be truthy). Is this some sort of misinterpretation on my behalf of how `takeUntil`/`takeWhile` works?

As a workaround, I'm currently using this:

```
const takeWhileAsync = (predicate = tautology) => {
  const resultSymbol = Symbol('predicateResult');
  const valueSymbol = Symbol('value');

  const predicateResolver = item => of(item).pipe(
    concatMap(async (i) => {
      const predicateResult = await predicate(i);
      return {[resultSymbol]: predicateResult, [valueSymbol]: i};
    }),
  );

  return pipe(
    concatMap(predicateResolver),
    takeWhile(({[resultSymbol]: predicateResult}) => predicateResult),
    pluck(valueSymbol),
  );
};
```

Comment: [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeUntil) doesn't accept a predicate to be called with each emitted item, it accepts a "notifier", an observable that emits when it's time to stop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a method to exit early from a pipe without needing to create a notifier observable? Ideally I'd like to pass in a predicate (as with `takeWhile`) but have that predicate be an async function (which `takeWhile` seemed to always coerce to a truthy value)

Comment: An async function should be corrected to a function that returns a promise, sorry

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware; as you've seen `takeWhile` requires a predicate returning a boolean, not an promise of one (which is indeed truthy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Idiomatic RxJS

Most RxJS operators (`concatMap`, `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, ect...) take `ObservableInput` as the returned values (meaning they work with Promises natively).

This is a take on @'Nick Bull's answer that doesn't do any `promise (async/await)` stuff. This way you can use promises or (as is probably advisable), stick entirely with Observables.

```ts
function takeWhileConcat<T>(genPred: (v:T) => ObservableInput<Boolean>): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>{
  return pipe(
    concatMap((payload: T) => from(genPred(payload)).pipe(
      take(1),
      map((pass: boolean) => ({payload, pass}))
    )),
    takeWhile(({pass}) => pass),
    map(({payload}) => payload)
  );
}

const items = [1,2,3,4,5];
const predicate = async (i) => i < 3;
const pipeline = from(items).pipe(
  takeWhileConcat(predicate),
);

pipeline.subscribe(console.log);
```

Now, if you wanted to, you can replace predicate with an observable:

`const predicate = i => of(i < 3);`

and not change anything else. Which is nice, because observables and promises sometimes don't play as nicely as you'd expect.

Consider that promises are eager and observables are lazy and you can get some strange execution orders that are tough to debug.

---

### This solution doesn't allow for non-promise predicates!

So, you're right. This solution requires you to return an `ObservableInput` (Any iterable, promise, or observable). Actually, any ES6 Iterable, so Arrays, Generators, Maps, HashMaps, Vectors, custom iterables, you name it. They'll all work.

- Observable: `predicate = value => of(value > 3)`
- Iterable: `predicate = value => [value > 3]`
- Promise: `predicate = value => Promise.resolve(value > 3)`
- Syntactic sugar for promise: `predicate = async value => value > 3`

What it does **not** allow is anything that isn't an `ObservableInput`. This matches how every other RxJS operator that takes an `ObservableInput` functions. Of course, we could martial any value as an observable using `of`, but this was decided against as it's much more likely to be a foot-gun than to be useful.

In a dynamically-typed language, it can be difficult to decide what your API allows vs where it should throw an error. I like that RxJS doesn't treat values as Observables by default. I think the RxJS api is much clearer for it.

Operators do a better job of making their intentions clear. Imagine these two were the same:

`map(x => x + 1)`
`mergeMap(x = x + 1)`

That second one could turn the returned value into an observable and merge that observable, but this requires a lot of specialized knowledge about this operator. Map, on the other hand, works exactly the same way it does on the other iterators/collections we're already familiar with.

#### How to accept a non-promise predicate

Anyway, all this to say, you can change my answer to accept a standard predicate (`v => boolean`) as well as an async predicate (`v => ObservableInput<boolean>`) if you so choose. Just supply a value and inspect what is returned.

I'm just not convinced this is desirable behavior.

### What if the input items are an infinite generator?

Here's an generator that generates integers forever.

```ts
const range = function*() { 
  for (let i = 0; true; i++) yield i; 
}
```

`from(range())` doesn't know when to stop calling the generator (or even that the generator is infinite). `from(range()).subscribe(console.log)` will print numbers to the console indefinitely.

The key here is that in such a case, the code that stops us from calling back to the generator must run synchronously.

For example:

```ts
from(range()).pipe(
  take(5)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

will print the numbers 0 - 4 to the console.

This is true for our custom operator as well. Code that still works:

```ts
from(range()).pipe(
  takeWhileConcat(v => of(v < 10))
).subscribe(console.log);

// or 

from(range()).pipe(
  takeWhileConcat(v => [v < 10])
).subscribe(console.log);
```

code that doesn't halt:

```ts
from(range()).pipe(
  takeWhileConcat(v => of(v < 10).pipe(
    delay(0)
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);

// or

from(range()).pipe(
  takeWhileConcat(async v => v < 10)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

That's a consequence of how javascript engine deals with async behavior. Any current code is run to completion before the engine looks at the event queue. Every promise is put in the event queue, and async observables are put on the event queue as well (which is why delay(0) is basically the same as a promise that resolves right away)

concatMap does have built-in backpressure, but the asynchronous part of the code never gets to run since the synchronous part of the code has created an infinite loop.

This is one of the downsides of a push-based streaming library (Like RxJS). If it were pull-based (like generators are), this wouldn't be an issue, but other issues emerge instead. You can google pull/push based streaming for lots of articles on the topic.

There are safe ways to interface pull-based and push-based streams, but it takes a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning about why not to use promises within these types of operators, that's really good knowledge for a newcomer! I understand it's probably better to stick with observables, and I'll look into how to write adapters for some of the libraries I'm using that are promise-based and how to convert them to observables

Comment: This solution doesn't allow for non-promise predicates! So wrapping any non-promise with `util.promisify` (or any other promisification) is needed. Is there a way around this, without the need for an external utility?

Comment: Just use `takeWhile` if you want to use a non-promise predicate?

Comment: I made an update to my answer. It doesn't implement this, but there's a hint for how it can be done.

Comment: That makes sense. One final addendum to this question - what if the input items are an infinite generator? e.g., `const range = function* () { for (let i = 0; true; i++) yield i; }`. `from(range()).pipe(takeWhileConcat(async i => i < 10)` seems to loop until a memory overflow, whereas `from(range()).pipe(takeWhile(i => i < 10))` does not! Really curious why this is the case as well - is this because `concatMap` iterates the entire collection before passing onto `takeWhile`?

Comment: @NickBull I've added another update to talk about why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> Ideally I'd like to pass in a predicate (as with takeWhile) but have that predicate be an async function (which takeWhile seemed to always coerce to a truthy value)

I believe you could do something like this:

```
const items [1,2,3,4,5];
const predicate = async (i) => i < 3;
const pipeline = from(items).pipe(
  concatMap(predicate),
  filter(Boolean),
  take(1)
);

pipeline.subscribe(console.log);
```

By doing this, you'll chain all your async calls (concatMap) but feel free to run them in // (mergeMap) or cancel them when there's a new value coming in (switchMap). Then you apply the filter **synchronously** which will only let the value that passes the predicate and the `take(1)` will put an end to the stream after the first value that passed the predicate.

**EDIT:**

Following this comment, here's the new solution:

```
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const predicate = async i => i < 3;
const pipeline = from(items).pipe(
  concatMap(item =>
    from(predicate(item)).pipe(
      filter(Boolean),
      mapTo(item)
    )
  )
);
```

Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yenhpy?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: This does seem to correctly utilise the predicate, but after quickly testing this the output is the boolean result, and not the values. I'm also not sure I need `take(1)`, as I only want to exit once the predicate is false. I am brand new to RxJS so forgive me if I'm misinterpreting!

Comment: Just to clarify the requirements further for the predicate `async (i) => i < 3` and for `items = [1,2,3,4,5]`, I want to receive 1 and 2

Comment: Oh I see, hold on

Comment: @NickBull I've made an edit :) let me know if that's what you want

Comment: Yes that works as expected - thanks Maxime!

Comment: Awesome. Hopefully the code makes sense, if not let me know I'll add some comments around it

Comment: The downside to filtering values rather that unsubscribing is that if there are expensive calculations upstream, you're going to continue to perform those. Replace predicate with `async i => i < 3 || i > 3` and you'll see that the later values continue to be processed. Which might not be desirable.

Comment: @MrkSef I have ran into the issue you have mentioned in this comment. However, your solution doesn't allow for non-promise predicates! So wrapping any non-promise with `util.promisify` (or any other promisification) is needed

Answer (score 0):

According to the question comments, there's no direct way to use `takeWhile` for this.

Here's the improved workaround from the above question, without the superfluous `of.pipe(concatMap)`:

```
const takeWhileAsync = (predicate = tautology) => {
  const resultSymbol = Symbol('predicateResult');
  const valueSymbol = Symbol('value');

  const predicateResolver = item => async (i) => {
    const predicateResult = await predicate(i);
    return {[resultSymbol]: predicateResult, [valueSymbol]: i};
  };

  return pipe(
    concatMap(predicateResolver),
    takeWhile(({[resultSymbol]: predicateResult}) => predicateResult),
    pluck(valueSymbol),
  );
};
```