# Using an async predicate with `takeWhile` on an infinite generator

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs, generator

Say I have the following generator that produces an infinite range:

```
const generateInfiniteRange = function* () {
  for (let i = 0; true; i++) {
    yield i;
  }
};
const infiniteRange = generateInfiniteRange();
const infiniteRange$ = from(infiniteRange);
```

I can do something like this with RxJS:

```
const predicate = i => i < 10;
infiniteRange$.pipe(
  takeWhile(predicate),
);
```

Now let's say that the predicate is asynchronous:

```
const predicate = async i => i < 10;

infiniteRange$.pipe(takeWhile(predicate)).subscribe(console.log);
```

How can I make this code work?

```
infiniteRange$.pipe(takeWhile(predicate));
```

I've tried using `map` as follows:

```
infiniteRange$.pipe(
  map(async i => ({
    i,
    predicateResult: await predicate(i),
  })),
  takeWhile(({predicateResult}) => predicateResult),
  pluck('i'),
);
```

but that just ends up mapping everything to a promise that always coerces to a truthy value, so everything passes through the `takeWhile`

I figured based on a [previous question I've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743703/passing-pipeline-item-to-promise-argument-in-takeuntil/68745545?noredirect=1#comment121518150_68745545) (for which originally I asked this question as an addendum in a comment of [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68745545/2483271), before deciding a question was more appropriate) that I could use `concatMap`, but that just generates an infinite emission before any of the internal observables hit the pipe.

Comment: Well what behavior you want to achieve? The generator will keep generating values and the predicate will be called asynchronously so at the moment the chain is completed because the predicate returns false you might have milions of predicate values stacked waiting (at least I think that's how it works). But it seems like you want the generator to yield a value, run the async predicate and when it resolves yield another value?

Comment: @martin For a predicate (e.g., `const predicate = async (i) => i < 3`), a) generate a single value (e.g., `1`), b) test the value by awaiting the predicate (e.g., `takeWhileAsync(predicate)`), c) complete the pipe operations, and repeat from a). Once `3` is generated, `takeWhileAsync` should return false, and the pipe should end. So to succinctly answer, I want an equivalent operator to `takeWhile` that accepts a promise instead of a function as the predicate. I think you've summarised the desired functionality I'm after in that last sentence of your comment well - is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need `concatMap` for this. So your actual problem is just that this doesn't work with infinite streams for some reason?

Comment: @Bergi That's correct! If I `tap(log)` I can see the iteration is definitely happening. If I further attempt `concat(i => from(i).pipe(...))` it ends up with a memory overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this right, you can not achieve what you want.

The simple reason is that when, with `from` you create an Observable out of a generator, then you are creating a **synchronous** Observable, i.e. an Observable which emits all its values synchronously.

You can see clearly this looking at the [`fromIterable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3a6d1643f6ef9cc28cce0051a805b9ce55ceb7a3/src/internal/observable/from.ts#L209) source code

```
function fromIterable<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
  return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => {
    for (const value of iterable) {
      subscriber.next(value);
      if (subscriber.closed) {
        return;
      }
    }
    subscriber.complete();
  });
}
```

As you can see, the `for` loop is exited only when the `subscriber` is closed. But in our case the `subscriber` will be closed asynchronously, i.e. we need Node to stop the execution of the loop since no instructions are left and pick the next callback, the one that runs the predicate. This will never happen since the `for` loop will never end.

So the summary is that you can not have an async predicate working with a synchronous infinite stream of values, which is what you create using a Generator.

By the way, in order for the code to compile, you need to use `concatMap` to transform the value notified by the source stream to the Object used by the predicate. So a code that compiles is this one

```
infiniteRange$.pipe(
  tap(i => {
    console.log(i)
  }),
  concatMap(async i => {
    console.log('concatMap hit');
    return {
      i,
      predicateResult: await predicate(i),
    }
  }),
  takeWhile(({predicateResult}) => {
    console.log('takeWhile hit');
    return predicateResult
  }),
  pluck('i'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Running this snippet, you will see that you enter once in the `concatMap` input function (i.e. "concatMap hit" will be printed once) while you never enter the function passed to `takeWhile` (i.e. "takeWhile hit" will never be printed).

**A SOLUTION WITH ASYNC GENERATORS**

Actually, if you change the generator to be `async`, then using `concatMap` in the `pipe` we can reach the result you are looking for.

This is how the code would look like

```
const generateInfiniteRangeAsync = async function* () {
  for (let i = 0; true; i++) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    yield i;
  }
};

const predicate = async i => i < 10;

const infiniteRangeAsync = generateInfiniteRangeAsync();
const infiniteRangeAsync$ = from(infiniteRangeAsync);

infiniteRangeAsync$.pipe(
  concatMap(async i => {
    console.log('concatMap hit');
    return {
      i,
      predicateResult: await predicate(i),
    }
  }),
  takeWhile(({predicateResult}) => {
    console.log('takeWhile hit');
    return predicateResult
  }),
  pluck('i'),
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: What a shame! :(

Comment: @Nick Bull I have added a possible way out for your problem

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), which can handle asynchronous predicates out of the box:

```
import {pipeAsync, stop} from 'iter-ops';

// your infinite generator:
const generateInfiniteRange = function * () {
    for (let i = 0; true; i++) {
        yield i;
    }
};

// create our iterable:
const i = pipeAsync(generateInfiniteRange(), stop(async a => a >= 10));

// test:
(async function () {
    for await(const a of i) {
        console.log(a); //=> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    }
})();
```

P.S. I am the author of the library.